# Android:Webview with link highlight

Tags: android, webview

I am working with WebView on android and can't seem to figure out how to make that orange highlight that appears in the stock browser to appear on my webview.

To make it clearer let me give you an example.

When in android browser if you click on a link/image/video it'll show you a orange colored rectangle overlayed over that object. 
But when i try the same with my webview it does not show anything and goes onto loading that link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh !! i feel such an idiot... the webview does the default highlighting , the only thing was i was not giving it focus.

adding this line solved my problem

> myWebView.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);

Comment: Because for an upcoming project I actually want the opposite, i.e. no highlighting: did the WebView work normally except for the highlighting when you didn't request focus? Your question suggests that, just wanted to confirm it. Thanks.

Comment: Where in the code did you put that line? I'm still wrestling with the same problem and can't seem to get the highlighting to show up.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add that sometimes the first link of a webview would be highlighted by default when the webview became visible-- you can get rid of that by calling "mWebView.clearFocus()"

Comment: Hi,
I am having the same problem now. When I open the webview by default some link on the page is getting highlighted with an orange rectangle.

I tried using clearFocus(), but it is of no user. How can I implement in such a way that the default highlight is gone, but the link are highlighted when clicked??