# Android WebView link highlight issue

Tags: android, css, hyperlink, webview, highlight

So I have a html app that I'm loading in a WebView. The thing is I want to use shouldOverrideUrlLoading not to load a specific link, when it gets clicked, so I return true in that method, not loading the url. This works great, but the link is getting highlighted as if it was clicked. Is there a way that I can remove the highlighting if the link was pressed but not loaded?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could have one of a few problems, [Clicking on the link in android webview does not get highlighted visually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8425969/clicking-on-the-link-in-android-webview-does-not-get-highlighted-visually) says you have to set Javascript as enabled with:

```
webView.getSettings().setJavascriptEnabled(true);
```

There's also been an issue with focus at [Android:Webview with link highlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886056/androidwebview-with-link-highlight), where you should request focus on your webview with:

```
webView.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
```